# Using elpy from a .bat started emacs

Tags: pyqgis, api

I use a .bat file to add qgis to python path then open that environnement in emacs. I am unable to find or set or install elpy in the .emacs file or the bat file.

The modules are installed but Emacs don't find them. I saw a similar post, but couldn't find an answer.

My bat file is the following:

```
@echo off
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\apps\grass\grass-6.4.4\etc\env.bat
@echo off
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-6.4.4\lib
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis
start "Emacs aware of Quantum GIS" /B "C:\tool\emacs\bin\runemacs.exe" %*
```

My emacs is the following:

```
;h_ttp://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_package_system.html
;h_ttp://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16831/using-package-el-to-install-and-update-but-use-package-for-loading-and-configuri

;; Added by Package.el. This must come before configurations of
;; installed packages. Don't delete this line. If you don't want it,
;; just comment it out by adding a semicolon to the start of the line.
;; You may delete these explanatory comments.

(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil) ; To prevent initialising twice

(add-to-list 'package-archives
'("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives
'("elpy" . "http://jorgenschaefer.github.io/packages/"))

(package-initialize t)

    ;("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
(package-refresh-contents)
(package-install 'use-package))

(eval-when-compile
(require 'use-package))

;; Elpy, the Emacs Lisp Python Environment
;; Initialize package mode along with all the installed packages

(use-package elpy ; The one and only Git frontend
:ensure t
:bind (("C-c v c" . elpy-jedi)
("C-c v v" . elpy-importmagic)
("C-c v g" . elpy-autopep8)
("C-c v l" . elpy-yapf)
("C-c v p" . elpy-pyflakes)
("C-c v p" . elpy-pyenv))
:config (setq elpy-save-repository-buffers 'dontask))

(elpy-enable)
(setq elpy-rpc-backend "jedi")

(elpy-mode)
;; Jedi backend

(jedi:setup)
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)

(custom-set-variables
;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.

'(company-auto-complete t)
'(elpy-mode-hook (quote (subword-mode hl-line-mode)))
'(package-selected-packages (quote (## elpy))))

(custom-set-faces
;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
)
```

I know there are issues in my emacs file.

When I open emacs normally. Elpy is listed in package list as installed but is not available (M-x elpy returns [no match].¸

More precisely if I use package-refresh-contents then package-list packages. elpy is listed as installed but no match.

If I uninstall and reinstall it I get the following elpy-config:

Elpy Configuration:

```
Virtualenv........: None
RPC Python........: 2.7.11 (c:/OSGeo4W/apps/Python27/pythonw.exe)
Interactive Python: python (c:/OSGeo4W/apps/Python27/python.exe)
Emacs.............: 25.1.1
Elpy..............: 1.12.0
Jedi..............: 0.9.0
Rope..............: Not found (0.10.3 available)
Importmagic.......: 0.1.7
Autopep8..........: 1.2.4
Yapf..............: 0.12.0
Syntax checker....: pyflakes.exe (c:/OSGeo4W/apps/Python27/Scripts/pyflakes.exe)
```

Also : Package list packages tells me pyenv is installed but not elpy.

```
elpy 1.12.0 installed Emacs Python Development Environment
company 0.9.0 dependency Modular text completion framework
find-file-in-pr... 3.3 dependency Find files in a project quickly.
highlight-inden... 0.6.0 dependency Function for highlighting indentation
pyvenv 1.9 dependency Python virtual environment interface
yasnippet 0.10.0 dependency
```

When I use my bat file to open emacs. The emacs file is not read and no modules are available.

So I have multiple issues:

I can't use elpy in a normally started emacs session.

How do I get it to work?

And I can't get it to work when started from my bat file.

I want an emacs environment in which I can use QGIS being auto-completed by elpy in emacs. I had big troubles getting QGIS to work outside the GUI... The bat file is how I managed it.